# OpenMP: splitting loop based on NUMA

Tags: multithreading, performance, openmp, affinity, numa

I am running the following loop using, say, 8 OpenMP threads:

```
float* data;
int n;

#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic, 1) default(none) shared(data, n)
for ( int i = 0; i < n; ++i )
{
    DO SOMETHING WITH data[i]
}
```

Due to NUMA, I'd like to run first half of the loop (i = 0, ..., n/2-1) with threads 0,1,2,3
and second half (i = n/2, ..., n-1) with threads 4,5,6,7.

Essentially, I want to run two loops in parallel, each loop using a separate group of OpenMP threads.

How do I achieve this with OpenMP?

Thank you

PS: Ideally, if threads from one group are done with their half of the loop, and the other half of the loop is still not done, I'd like threads from finished group join unsfinished group processing the other half of the loop.

I am thinking about something like below, but I wonder if I can do this with OpenMP and no extra book-keeping:

```
int n;
int i0 = 0;
int i1 = n / 2;

#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic, 1) default(none) shared(data,n,i0,i1)
for ( int i = 0; i < n; ++i )
{
    int nt = omp_get_thread_num();
    int j;
    #pragma omp critical
    {
        if ( nt < 4 ) {
            if ( i0 < n / 2 ) j = i0++; // First 4 threads process first half
            else              j = i1++; // of loop unless first half is finished
        }
        else {
            if ( i1 < n ) j = i1++;  // Second 4 threads process second half
            else          j = i0++;  // of loop unless second half is finished 
        }
    }

    DO SOMETHING WITH data[j]
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why you say "Due to NUMA, I'd like to run first half of the loop (i = 0, ..., n/2-1) with threads 0,1,2,3 and second half (i = n/2, ..., n-1) with threads 4,5,6,7."?

Comment: Because `data` is allocated in such way, that first half of it is close to one socket (where I run threads 0,1,2,3) and second half of it is close to another socket (where I run threads 4,5,6,7)

Comment: What is your OS and hardware and compiler? Linux? Two sockets Intel Xeon? Gcc?

Comment: @Zboson RHEL 6.3, 8-socket Xeon CPU E5-4640 (64 cores total). 1 TB memory. Example in the post is simplified. I need more than 2 groups of threads. Compiler: GCC 4.8.3 or latest Intel.

Comment: Are you sure you want `schedule(dynamic,1)` or do you want `sechedule(static)`?

Comment: dynamic, because execution time for different `i` can be different. And block size is `1`, because of cache misses (I don't want to go into details of DO SOMETHING part of the code)

Comment: You can use numactl on the command line or set_schedaffinity to pin threads to particular cores, but the nicer approach is to make sure your data is in the right place for the threads by initializing the data with OMP threads, to make sure the data and the threads are collocated.

Comment: Threads are pinned, data is allocated close to threads. That's not an issue. The issue is loop splitting code.

Comment: Ahh - finally understand.  Interesting.

Comment: In my experience in Linux the threads are scattered. So thread 0 would got to socket 0, thread 1 to socket 1, and so forth (windows uses compact). The way you describe appears to be the compact form. Are you sure that's the correct topology?

Comment: I set, KMP_AFFINITY appropriately. So threads run where I tell them to run.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably best is to use nested parallelization, first over NUMA nodes, then within each node; then you can use the infrastructure for `dynamic` while still breaking the data up amongst thread groups:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    const int ngroups=2;
    const int npergroup=4;
    const int ndata = 16;

    omp_set_nested(1);
    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(ngroups)
    for (int i=0; i<ngroups; i++) {
        int start = (ndata*i+(ngroups-1))/ngroups;
        int end  = (ndata*(i+1)+(ngroups-1))/ngroups;    

        #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(npergroup) shared(i, start, end) schedule(dynamic,1)
        for (int j=start; j<end; j++) {
            printf("Thread %d from group %d working on data %d\n", omp_get_thread_num(), i, j);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Running this gives

```
$ gcc -fopenmp -o nested nested.c -Wall -O -std=c99
$ ./nested | sort -n -k 9
Thread 0 from group 0 working on data 0
Thread 3 from group 0 working on data 1
Thread 1 from group 0 working on data 2
Thread 2 from group 0 working on data 3
Thread 1 from group 0 working on data 4
Thread 3 from group 0 working on data 5
Thread 3 from group 0 working on data 6
Thread 0 from group 0 working on data 7
Thread 0 from group 1 working on data 8
Thread 3 from group 1 working on data 9
Thread 2 from group 1 working on data 10
Thread 1 from group 1 working on data 11
Thread 0 from group 1 working on data 12
Thread 0 from group 1 working on data 13
Thread 2 from group 1 working on data 14
Thread 0 from group 1 working on data 15
```

But note that the nested approach may well change the thread assignments over what the one-level threading would be, so you will probably have to play with KMP_AFFINITY or other mechanisms a bit more to get the bindings right again.

Comment: That's a clever answer. I have not used `omp_set_nested` yet.

Comment: Thanks - once I finally understood the question, it mapped nicely onto this.

Comment: Thanks. I guess you could also use tasks in outer loop. Don't know if it makes a difference.
I am also trying to understand omp teams construct (never used them before). Can this feature be used instead of nested parallelism?

Comment: Tasks or parallel for at the top level, it doesn't really matter - whatever makes it easier to read or write.  The nice thing about the  loop is that it generalizes easily to different number of top level numa nodes.  Teams do refer to nested parallelism, although be careful - in OMP 4, teams refers to the accelerator (GPU/Phi) stuff.

Comment: @JonathanDursi I just implemeted your approach in my code and tested it on a 2-socket (16-core total) machine. With old code, execution time dropped from 55 seconds to 50 when going from 8 threads to 16. With NUMA-aware code, 16-thread test runs in 32 seconds!

Comment: The thread topology for the OP's question is compact. How could this be done if the thread topology is scattered (which is the default for Linux)? For example with eight threads the even threads (0,2,4,6)  would map to one socket and the odd threads (1,3,5,7) to another socket. It seems that the scattered topology is not very useful for this?