# Determine socket/processor of running thread

Tags: c, multithreading, openmp, numa

I writing NUMA-aaware cache for large objects (matrices of doubles) for 4 socket server. I observe that intersocket communication is the bottleneck for my application. Hence, I want threads on different sockets to have separate matrix caches. I have bounded threads to specific physical processors and now I need to make threads select correct cache.

Suppose cache is defined in the following way:

```
matrix_cache_t *cache[SOCKETS_LIMIT];
```

I need each thread to know its socket id and select correct cache, e.g. `cache[0]`, `cache[1]`, `cache[2]` or `cache[3]`.

I am writing the application in C using OpenMP and it is supposed to run on both Windows and Linux.

Comment: What platform are you in?

Comment: x86 and x86-64, only recent hardware support is required, as application already depends on SSE4 instruction set

Comment: consider [hwloc](http://www.open-mpi.org/projects/hwloc/]) and read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14720642/openmp-parallel-for-region-thread-affinity

Comment: and see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24957781/openmp-splitting-loop-based-on-numa/24959025#24959025

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under Windows you can use the [`GetLogicalProcessorInformationEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd405488(v=vs.85).aspx) API using either the `RelationNumaNode` or `RelationProcessorPackage` relation. It gives you the bits of all the processors in the respective relationship, which correspond to the affinity bits used to tie a thread to a processor.

Under Linux you can use `sched_getcpu`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sched.h>

int sched_getcpu();

int main()
{
    (void) printf("cpu %d\n", sched_getcpu());
}
```

Socket id can be found in `/proc/cpuinfo` or `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/topology/physical_package_id`

Comment: @Fredrik Widlund - Thanks for adding the Linux part. Made it CW.

Comment: @Fredrik Widlund - very useful. Do you know how to get from sched_getcpu() to socket id? Thank you

Comment: @cdome I suspect you'd have to parse `/proc/cpuinfo` for that. Mind that the format of this file is architecture-dependent.

Comment: @duskwuff - I agree, both cpuinfo and /sys/devices/system/cpu/... are AFAIK platform dependent. (btw, just now reached enough rep to comment here, which is why I answered in the post)